# Collection repeat with ng-if causing an 'webkitTransform' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use `ng-if` in a collection repeat in order to hide some list items and I am having with an error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'webkitTransform' of undefined

This is how I am using it:

```
<div collection-repeat="item in container.items" ng-if="item.isShowing">
...
...
...
</div>
```

It works if I use ng-repeat though.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should filter on specific property

```
<div collection-repeat="item in container.items| filter : {isShowing: true}">
```